# How to go through Outlook emails in reverse order using Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I want to read my Outlook emails and only the Unread ones. The code that I have right now is:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst ()
while message:
    if message.Unread == True:
        print (message.body)
        message = messages.GetNext ()
```

But this goes from the first email to last email. I want to go in the reverse order because unread emails will be on the top. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: well wouldn't that just change message = messages.GetFirst() ? to messages.GetLast() if that exists or look for a function to do something similar

Comment: Yes, there's a `GetLast` and also a `GetPrevious` method. It should be self-evident how to get them in reverse order...

Comment: `GetLast()` and `GetNext()` don't work together @OmidCompSCI and I could not find `GetPrevious()`. Thank you @kindall

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with cole that a for loop is good for going through all of them. If starting from the most recently-received email is important (e.g. for a specific order, or for limiting how many emails you go through), you can use the [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-sort-method-outlook) function to sort them by the [Received Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-receivedtime-property-outlook) property.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
#the Sort function will sort your messages by their ReceivedTime property, from the most recently received to the oldest.
#If you use False instead of True, it will sort in the opposite direction: ascending order, from the oldest to the most recent.
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for message in messages:
     if message.Unread == True:
         print (message.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a for loop? To go through your messages from first to last like it appears you are trying to do.

```
for message in messages:
     if message.Unread == True:
         print (message.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old question but this is one of the top posts on Google for this question so I'd like to add my experience.

Use of a for loop in iterating through messages is a more "pythonic" way of structuring your code, however in my experience it often causes failures with this specific library/API as any external changes (e.g. an email being moved to another folder while the program is iterating) can cause the dreaded 4096 exception.

Additionally, you will find that any non-emails (e.g. meeting invites) can cause unexpected results / exceptions.

I therefore use code that's a mesh of the original poster's code, Bex Way's accepted answer, and my own discoveries:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
message = messages.GetFirst ()
while message:
    if message.Class != 43: #Not an email - ignore it
        message = messages.GetNext ()
    elif message.Unread == True:
        print (message.body)
        message = messages.GetNext ()
```