# Pulling a list of outlook email received dates using Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to extract a list of received dates of all emails in a specific folder within an outlook mailbox (with the intention of filtering them for specific dates later). I'm a complete beginner with Python and I've managed to get into the correct subfolder and can pull a list out, however, the list is made up of the same received date and time over and over again - the whole list is one single date. I've doubled checked this by pulling subject line and its definitely just pulling from a single email and repeating it throughout the list.

How do I get the list to comprise of all the received dates of all the emails in the folder rather than just one?

```
import win32com.client
import os 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
mailbox = outlook.Folders.Item("$OutlookMailbox")
inbox = mailbox.Folders.Item("Inbox")
pega = inbox.Folders.Item("InboxSubfolder")

messages = InboxSubfolder.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject  = message.subject
sender = message.sender
received_date = message.ReceivedTime

for message in messages:
    print(received_date)
```

'''

I've tried:
message.

- GetFirst()
- GetLast()
- GetNext()
- GetPrevious()

and nothing is changing the output.

Comment: Couldn't you use bs4

Comment: @BrodyCritchlow No, in this case ([tag:win32com]) we use the [COM interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) of locally installed Microsoft applications like _Outlook_. However, with [tag:bs4] you could later scrape the HTML-body of an email.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

When do you define `received_date` ?

In below line marked with the comment. The line is outside the loop, and the date is from the first message. So it stays the same during the loop - unless you assign it new inside the loop.

```py
messages = InboxSubfolder.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subject  = message.subject
sender = message.sender
received_date = message.ReceivedTime  # date of first message

for message in messages:
    print(received_date)
```

#### Similar solution

Have you tried:

```py
# Count all items in the sub-folder
item_count = InboxSubfolder.Items.Count

if item_count > 0:
    for i in range(item_count, 0, -1):
        message = InboxSubfolder.Items[i]
        print(message.received_date)  # received date from current message
```

I found it on [Python Outlook - Loop through Outlook emails in folder - pywin32 | EXCELCISE](https://www.excelcise.org/python-outlook-iterate-through-email-in-outlook-folder-pywin32/).
There is a link to the [GitHub repo with example `iterate_emails_in_a_folder.py`](https://github.com/gygergely/PythonOutlook/blob/master/03_Iterate%20Outlook%20emails/iterate_emails_in_a_folder.py).

#### Alternative: use iterator methods (`GetFirst` and `GetNext`)

See
[How to go through Outlook emails in reverse order using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428770/how-to-go-through-outlook-emails-in-reverse-order-using-python)

```py
message = messages.GetFirst()
while message:  # find a suitable exit-condition!
    message = messages.GetNext()
```