# win32com Outlook subfolder not always found

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have a script that moves/saves/categorizes emails in a shared mail. And I'm encountering errors when sometimes mail folders are not found. I'm using below function to retrieve mail folders. And sometimes it works and othertimes it doesn't. I usually have to restart outlook to make it work once the error has been thrown. It sometimes fails to find the subfolders within the `Inbox` and it returns that it is empty.

Is there anyway to ensure that the subfolders are always found?

```py
OUTLOOK = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') #This is how I dispatch outlook
```

```py
Mapi - folders
['x', 'y', 'z',]

x - folders
['PersonMetadata', 'Yammer Root', 'Tasks', 'Sent Items', 'Outbox', 'Notes', 'Junk Email', 'Journal', 'Inbox', 'Files', 'ExternalContacts', 'Drafts', 'Deleted Items', 'Conversation History', 'Conversation Action Settings', 'Contacts', 'Calendar', 'Archive']

Inbox - folders
['a', 'b', 'c'] #THIS IS SOMETIMES EMPTY
```

```py
FOLDERS = {"example": ["x", "Inbox", "a"]}

def get_folder(outlook_instance, *folders):
    target_folder = outlook_instance
    try:
        for folder in folders:
            print(folder_path)
            print([f.Name for f in target_folder.Folders])
            target_folder = target_folder.Folders[str(folder)]
    except Exception:
        raise ValueError("".join(f".Folders[{folder}]" for folder in folders))
    return target_folder 

def get_outlook_folder(folder, outlook):
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    return get_folder(mapi, *FOLDERS.get(folder))
```

I found this on an other post that I think relates to my issue, but I don't really understand what it is saying stackoverflow.com/a/40853098/10833061

Comment: Can we see the code where you call `get_folder`, eg what is `outlook_instance` set to?

Answer (score 0):

Is Outlook always running on the system when your code is executed?

Otherwise, you need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance and logon to the profile to be able to access folders. I am not a python developer, so here is a C# sample code which illustrates the required workflow for you:

```
 Outlook.Application GetApplicationObject()
        {

            Outlook.Application application = null;

            // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
            {

                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
            }
            else
            {

                // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and sign in to the default profile.
                application = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                nameSpace = null;
            }

            // Return the Outlook Application object.
            return application;
        }
```

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so I hope there you won't find any difficulties in understanding the required approach. Read more about that in the [Get and sign in to an instance of Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-and-log-on-to-an-instance-of-outlook?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article in MSDN.

Finally, it is not clear what comes from where - I'd recommend clarifying all bits in the sample code posted, so we could suggest anything else.

Comment: Outlook is always running, my dispatch function is like the sample code you provided, but since I always have outlook running it's always that I dispatch an active instance. I can always find the top level folders e.g., my own mail and the shared mail and it's inbox. But when I try to go deeper it sometimes fails to find those subfolder.

Comment: I found this on an other post that I think relates to my issue, but I don't really understand what it is saying https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853098/10833061

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I've experienced similar issues; when connecting to Outlook via the Outlook object model it sometimes just doesn't display any of the existing subfolders, and "folder.Folders.Count" shows as zero. I've experienced this in both
Python and VBA, and have found a Python solution!

Despite being an old question, this is the top result on Google for this query, so I hope this answer helps future searchers.

Here's my code, with only one line added that appears to resolve this.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import json
import datetime as dt

def process_folder(folder, emails_list):
    emailSearchDate = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=13)
    emails = folder.Items
    #True here means in descending order e.g. newest to oldest.
    emails.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    #We use the try/except pattern along with "while email", instead of e.g. "for email in emails", ref to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428770/how-to-go-through-outlook-emails-in-reverse-order-using-python/76569271#76569271 for reasons why
    try:
        email = emails.GetFirst()
    except:
        email = None
    while email:
        #Only process emails, not other types of items like calendar invites, contacts etc.
        if email.Class == 43:
            email_details = {
                "Subject": str(email.Subject),
                "Sender": str(email.SenderEmailAddress),
                "SenderName": str(email.Sender),
                "Received Time": str(email.ReceivedTime),
                "Body": str(email.Body),
                "Recipients": '',
                "RecipientName": str(email.To)
            }
            for recipient in email.Recipients:
                email_details['Recipients'] += recipient.Address + ';'
            emails_list.append(email_details)
        #Move on to the next item. If there aren't any more items, it'll set to None and break the loop
        if email.Class == 43 and email.ReceivedTime.replace(tzinfo=None) < emailSearchDate:
            email = None
        else:
            try:
                email = emails.GetNext()
            except:
                email = None
    #For this Stackoverflow query, the next line is the crucial one!
    #My hypothesis is that printing folder.Folders forces Outlook to enumerate the folders instead of relying on a sometimes-empty cache?
    #However, frankly, this is a guess only - I don't know the inner workings of the Outlook object model.
    print(folder, folder.Folders)
    #Without the above line, sometimes folder.Folders.Count is zero even though there are many subfolders.
    if folder.Folders.Count > 0:
        for subfolder in folder.Folders:
            process_folder(subfolder, emails_list)


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
mailbox_folder = namespace.Folders.Item("EXAMPLE@EMAIL.COM").Folders("Inbox")
email_list = []
process_folder(mailbox_folder, email_list)

fileName = r'outputfile.json'
print("Saving data to " + fileName)
with open(fileName,"w") as write_file:
    json.dump(email_list, write_file, default=str)
```